# Localize TextField's default context menu

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a problem with translating default context menu items on `TextField`. There's no documentation about this menu in `JavaFX` javadocs (at least I couldn't find the one).

[image: context menu on a TextField]

I can manually create new context menu on each `TextField`, rewrite the exising code and just change displayed text, but is there a sense in that? I can't believe that no one thought about this when designing `JavaFX` components.

So, my question is - is there a way to overwrite these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text displayed in the context menu is stored in properties files that are read into a resource bundle. There is a collection of properties files with somewhat limited support for different languages. You can see these files in the [source code repository](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/f89b7dc932af/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/resources).

It seems to be quite hard to add support for unsupported languages on the fly: there is a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25791416/localizing-javafx-controls/25794018#25794018) - though I am still hoping someone who understands better than I how to do this may add a better answer to that.

In the meantime you might want to file a request at [JIRA](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/) for support for additional languages - better still provide a properties file for your language of interest by translating the values in those linked above and submit it.