# JavaFX 8 Localization of dialog's internal elements

Tags: java, javafx, localization, javafx-8

I am currently developing a JavaFX application with Slovak language localization and inside the application I am using an `Alert` dialog for showing exceptions with expandable content pane as shown below on images:

[image: show details - alert screen]
[image: hide details - alert screen]

I would like to have this dialog completely translated which is going well with `Header`, `Title` or `Content` but I cannot find a way how to translate the `Show/Hide details` label of the expandable area.

So my question can be a little bit generalized: How to change/translate text of JavaFX internal elements?

Thanks in advance for any help.

PS: For creation of this Alert dialog for exceptions I am using code as found on [code.makery.ch](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/#exception-dialog)

Comment: looks like a bug to me - if the Locales are available, all localizable strings should be translated. You might consider filing a report in fx issue tracker (if it's still online, heard it will be merged with core jdk tracker sometime this month)

Comment: @kleopatra I am not using correct localization with setting Locales or something. I just set all labels that have available public setters. Should I use correct localization to solve it?

Comment: hmm .. Slovak isn't provided by core jdk? Or just not by fx?

Comment: @kleopatra No, Slovak language is not betwwen default Locales.

Comment: oops, that's bad :-( Faintly remember that there's a way to hook a custom locale provider into the system, but don't remember any details, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your particular use case, you can add another listener to `expandedProperty` which will override the texts shown of "details button":

```
Platform.runLater(() ->
{
    Hyperlink detailsButton = ( Hyperlink ) alert.getDialogPane().lookup( ".details-button" );

    alert.getDialogPane().expandedProperty().addListener(
            ( ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue ) ->
    {
        detailsButton.setText( newValue ? "My less text" : "My more text" );
    });

    // trigger listeners
    alert.getDialogPane().setExpanded( true );
    alert.getDialogPane().setExpanded( false );
});
```

For more common hack see [Localizing JavaFx Controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25791416/localizing-javafx-controls). From there you need to put the following keys to your custom properties file:

```
// translate these
Dialog.detail.button.more = Show Details
Dialog.detail.button.less = Hide Details
```

Comment: This looks really good but I've got problem to lookup the ```.details-button``` hyperlink. In debugger I can see that ```dialogPane``` has property ```detailsButton``` but the lookup method returns ```null``` and I don't know how to get it from there. I've tried several variations of string but with no success.

Comment: @Supermartzin Works for me. You probably didn't put your code inside Platform.runLater().

Comment: @NikšaBaldun Thanks! I forgot that part and I also found out that I have been using another property. Now everything works well!