# JavaFx dialog doesn't show all content text

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have the following dialog:
[image]

The last line shows only part of the text - the text is cut and instead of text "..." is shown. How can I make the dialog show all text?
**EDIT 1**

This is the code

```
Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
alert.setTitle("Выход из программы");
alert.setHeaderText("Вы действительно хотите выйти из программы?");
alert.setContentText("Нажмите ОК для выхода. Для продолжения работы с программой нажмите Отмена.");
Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
if (result.get() == ButtonType.OK){

} else {

}
```

**EDIT 2**
This problem appears only in linux (centos 7.1 and gnome 3). In windows 7 all the text is shown at two lines and everything is ok.

**EDIT 3**

I think it's linked with the height of the dialog window. As When I `alert.setResizable(true)` and increase the height of the window the second line appears.

Comment: In order to *allow* people to help you, you should always post some code accompanying your question. Please add the relevant code of yours or at least snippets with the relevant parts.

Comment: @dot_Sp0T You are right. See edit 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't dig deeper for the reason, but alternatively you can set inner dialog pane's content instead:

```
alert.getDialogPane().setContent( new Label("твое содержание текста"));
```

**Edit:**

> Maybe you know how to change the text of the Cancel button?

you can lookup the "Cancel" button from dialog pane:

```
Button cancelButton = ( Button ) alert.getDialogPane().lookupButton( ButtonType.CANCEL );
cancelButton.setText("Oтмена");
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Maybe you know how to change the text of the Cancel button? The problem is I can't find way to get the reference to this bundle.

Comment: @iJava, follow [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30215178) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25794018).

Comment: @iJava alternatively you may build your own buttons and put via createButtonBar(). Refer to Alert javadoc.

Comment: Thank you for help. Looking for node via lookup seems to be a better solution for my case. The problem is how to find out the css if of the button :) I tried the ".cancel-button", however it returns null.

Comment: Thank you. I did it. ButtonBar buttonBar=(ButtonBar) alert.getDialogPane().lookup( ".button-bar" );   Button button=(Button) buttonBar.getButtons().get(0);  I think there is no another way to get css id - http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u40/rt/file/6cc08ec1ea82/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css

Comment: @iJava, actually dialogpane provides access its default buttons in its buttonBar. Get alert.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes() obseravlelist and traverse it, and get the ButtonType with ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE.

Comment: Imo its more safer. And you may accept the answer if it is **an** answer.

Comment: Can you show the example how to get reference to button via ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE?